# How to install BURG on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: grub2, 18.04, themes, customization, burg

Is there a way to install burg theme with **grub-customizer** or is there any other installer for it?
Because I did not find any.

Comment: Burg is obsolete and not really maintained since 2010. Since all new systems in last 5 years are UEFI, and if you install in UEFI boot mode and really want a gui boot manager, you can use rEFInd. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: My PC is old, my boot mode is BIOS. @oldfred

`Motherboard - G41MT-S2P`
`CPU - Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz`

Comment: I change grub to 3 sec, so it is not on screen for long, just enough time to change default if desired. But you can manually make some changes: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays